# how can I save the html to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://codepen.io/kevinchappell/pen/mPQMYZ

```
function showPreview() {
    let formRenderOpts = {
        formData: fbTemplate.value,
        render: false
      },
      renderedForm = new FormRenderFn(formRenderOpts).markup,
      html = `<!doctype html><title>Form Preview</title><body>${renderedForm}</body></html>`;
    var formPreviewWindow = '';//window.open('', 'formPreview', 'height=480,width=640,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes');

    formPreviewWindow.document.write(html);
    var style = document.createElement('link');
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));
    style.setAttribute('href', '//formbuilder.online/assets/css/form-render.min.css');
    style.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    style.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    formPreviewWindow.document.head.appendChild(style);    
 }
```

Instead of opening the html using window.open, how can I save the html to a variable?

Comment: you mean like style.innerHTML?

Comment: actually it would be outerHTML if you want to include `<link href="...`

Comment: @Assimilater I want the whole html. if possible I want to download it when user click save.

Comment: are you trying to render html? are you wanting the html as a string?

Comment: you want all of the document html? doctype included?

Comment: @Assimilater yes. when user open it it will render well in browser.

Comment: You should reword your question. You say "how can I save the html to a variable?"

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you make your title that....I mean that's what you did say, in your last sentence. It doesn't seem to be what you want

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery available, it's simple to just use the `jQuery/$` constructor shortcut to turn your HTML string into a jQuery object. You can then use jQuery's append methods to more succinctly append your stylesheet.

The resulting object can then either be inserted in to the document, or have return the full HTML with jQuery's `html()` method.

```
var formRenderOpts = {
        formData: fbTemplate.value,
        render: false
      },
      renderedForm = new FormRenderFn(formRenderOpts).markup,
      html = $('<!doctype html><head><title>Form Preview</title></head><body>' + renderedForm + '</body></html>');

 html.find('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="//formbuilder.online/assets/css/form-render.min.css"></style>');

//Output the HTML:
console.log(html.html());
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the OP...they have a DOM element and want the (string/some other format?)

Comment: The OP's example has a string representing HTML, not a DOM element, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: based on follow up comments, perhaps this is the answer the OP is looking for....

Comment: html.find is not a function

Comment: @EuniceChia did you use the line `html = $(....)`? Did you include jquery in your head?

Comment: I have this `function showPreview() {
  let formRenderOpts = {
      formData: fbTemplate.value,
      render: false
    },
    renderedForm = new FormRenderFn(formRenderOpts).markup,
    html = `<!doctype html><title>Form Preview</title><body>${renderedForm}</body></html>`;
  html.find('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="//formbuilder.online/assets/css/form-render.min.css"></style>');

  console.log(html.html());
}
`

Comment: @EuniceChia - I think your last code example has been broken by the comment formatting. `html.find` will be a function, as long as you initialise html with a jQuery object: `var html =  $('<html>...</html>')`